# Vue Router resolve view change only when all components in view have fetched their required data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In Vue I have created complete SFC components which fetch, render and interact with data all on their own. I just have to pass it the respective API endpoint as a prop and the CRUD logic always stays the same. The data fetching is activated using `onMounted` and `onBeforeRouteChange`.

The component is empty until it has received a reply from the backend. I *could* display a loader while the data is fetching. However, if there are multiple components with loading animations and different load times, then that is bad UX and the user might get confused why the view keeps changing.

Therefore I would like to render the complete Router view only once all the data-fetching components have emitted some kind of ready status.

I know you could fetch the data in the navigation guards, e.g., `beforeResolve`, but all of the navigation guards (with `afterEach` being the exception) activate before the view component is mounted. This means that any logic in the view component starts happening only once it is visible.

My best case scenario would be:

1. User clicks on a `<RouterLink :to="nextView">`.
2. The page displays a global loading bar, **the view doesn't change**.
3. All child components in `nextView` start fetching their data.
4. Once all child components in `nextView` have fetched their data, **the view gets rendered/changes**.
5. The loading bar disappears.

I have tried making all the data-fetching components emit some kind of ready status, then make the view component modify a global store to represent ready status once all of its' components are ready. I would then try to wait for that ready status in the `beforeResolve` navigation guard, but, again, beforeResolve does not mount the component, which means that it will never receive the status change.

Comment: Can we put the loader in some kind of super-parent component and the loader will stop when all child components emit ready status?

Comment: @NehaSoni the loader can be wherever, I can just use a global store to keep track of the loading status. The issue is keeping the previous Router view rendered while the new view starts loading in the background.

Comment: The reason why you can't find much about this pattern is because it's considered detrimental for UX, by any metric. Not doing anything until data for next view has loaded is very bad UX. You need to let the user know their action was registered and the app is working on it, not let them wonder if the app registered the interaction. The best UX is to make their "wait" pleasant via discrete animations and give them, where possible, some indication about how much more it's going to last until they receive the page. Typically you should prioritise rendering the "above the fold" of each view.

Comment: @tao I understand that the user needs some indication of the app registering their action. What I'm trying to avoid is rendering an empty page and populating it with data afterwards, which creates this jumpy mess of loading components. That's why I wanted to keep the previous view rendered and display a single loader while fetching the data.

Comment: You're trying to reduce [CLS](https://web.dev/cls/) by increasing [FCP](https://web.dev/fcp/). Reducing CLS is good and important, but not as important as not keeping low FCP and TTFB. Page loading is a vast subject. I'd recommend [web.dev](https://web.dev/), [PSI](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started) and [Tips for authoring fast pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Author_fast-loading_HTML_pages). Displaying the old page while loading the resources for next one is not a good pattern, that's certain.

Comment: The CLS page is quite informative and gives you a good overview. You should probably not load data from components, but rather have an API module which handles all requests. You can have an axios interceptor which controls the display of a loading indicator while resources are loading and managing which requests should be excepted from it. You might want to use skeletons while data loads, to reduce CLS.

Comment: @tao the backend contains microservices, which is why I am dividing data fetching into components (a single component fetches data from a single service). I created this post with the thought that someone might offer a better alternative to my thought process. I will try to replan the project structure to include an API module. Do you have any sources on keeping data fetching separate from components?

Comment: You are already using an API module (most likely `axios`). The need for one is driven by more than just good UX (e.g: ability to mock data loading in unit tests). Axios provides [interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) which could be used to solve this problem, once you have the UX defined. An alternative solution could be using the experimental built-in Vue 3 `<Suspense />` component. I'd argue what you need most is a UX designer. The problem with your question is you are asking about implementation details of something that's not yet clearly defined (the UX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to trigger component mounted hook or even to set its state without mounting it. Also, you cannot mount the next route component, while keeping rendered the previous route component.

My suggestion is to connect a centralised store to each child component (You can connect to it also independently only passing the store identifier). This way you can populate the store before mounting the component and then connect to it afterwards.

Now, you only need a way to tell the router guard which store to populate before navigating to a specific route. I suggest to set this information in route metadata, for example create an array of vuex namespaces on which a specific action should be triggered.

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta && to.meta.childStores) {
    // setting a loading flag in a global vuex module to trigger the loader
    store.commit("setLoading", true);
    // Dispatching the actions in each vuex module required for this route 
    for (let s of to.meta.childStores) {
      await store.dispatch(`${s}/fetchData`);
    }
    // disabling the loader after all requests have finished and proceeding to the next route
    store.commit("setLoading", false);
    next();
  }
  store.commit("setLoading", false);
  next();
});
```

You can view this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-loader-router-components-so-lh2tqg?file=/src/main.js:577-899) with a minimal working example.